# Is it necessary to synchronize access to a simple value when used from multiple queues?

Tags: ios, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

Consider the following example:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
{
    UIDeviceOrientation _orientation;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    _orientation = device.orientation;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
        // setting _orientation happens on the main thread
        _orientation = device.orientation;
    }];

    return YES;
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    // accessing _orientation on a background queue
    [self _doStuffWithBuffer:sampleBuffer orientation:_orientation];
}

@end
```

I have camera buffers coming in on a background queue. In order to process them I need access to the current device orientation. However, getting that requires access from the main queue.

In examples like this, is it fine if the main queue is occasionally writing to simple values while the background queue is reading them? I could wrap all reads and writes in an os_unfair_lock but I am hoping to avoid the perf hit of taking a lock in the read case which happens a lot.

If this example is ok, in what cases is it not ok? I assume reading/writing objects is a no-go; what about structs?